# Qt - QCheckBox does not emit stateChanged(int state) signal

Tags: c++, qt

i'm having an issue with the following signal-slot

```
QCheckBox *hasNotify = new QCheckBox;
connect(hasNotify, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int state)), this, SLOT(showhideNotify(int state)));
```

I get this in my application output

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QCheckBox::stateChanged(int state)
```

But here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#stateChanged they say this signal is included in QCheckBox, so I'm confused about what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

signal and slots parameters must not contain any variable names, so you should write

```
connect(hasNotify, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(showhideNotify(int)));
```

Take a look at documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect)

Comment: Thank you this indeed solved my problem, I'm still new to Qt, thank you :)